# How to print group membership in groupify

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [Groupify gem](https://github.com/dwbutler/groupify) to create separate roles in groups such as "
manager" "accountint" etc. In documentation is clear how to add object to groups with certaing membership: `group.add(user, as: 'manager')`. But there's no explanation how to check user memberships in certain group. I want to create admin panel for changing user roles and groups so it's very important.

#### Edit

I solved my problem

```
memberships = user.group_memberships_as_member.where("group_id = ?", group.id)
memberships.each do |membership|
 if membership.membership_type.present?
   puts membership.membership_type
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `user.in_named_group?(:admin)` (e.g. to check if admin is in the group.)

**You can also do this:**

```
User.in_any_group(group1, group2) # Find users that belong to any of these groups
```